# SharePoint - Calculated column filter shows formula instead of values

Tags: calculated-column, filter

The List in the view displays calculated column values correctly, but when I filter the same column it shows the formula instead of values. How can I resolve this to show calculated values in the filter.

My formula in the calculated column is -

```
="<img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' onload=""{"&" var day=new Date();"&" var SPday=new Date(); "&"  SPday.setFullYear("&YEAR(ITGCreationDate)&","&MONTH(ITGCreationDate)-1&","&DAY(ITGCreationDate)&");"&" var m=Math.ceil(Math.abs(SPday.getTime()-day.getTime()) /(1000*3600*24)); "&" this.parentNode.innerHTML=m; "&"}"">"
```

And here is the display of filter, showing formula, not values.

[image]

And this image is of the same calculated column, without filter, showing value.
[image]
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218822/javascript-code-in-the-sharepoint-2013-calculated-column), using javascript in calculated columns has been deprecated

[On June 13th 2017 all SharePoint calculated columns with HTML markup stopped working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f)

Comment: There you have it. So it seems there is no easy solution available as of now. Thank you for taking the time to post this useful message.

Comment: Hi Emaborsa, can you please take a look at this SharePoint workflow question that is receiving no attention. Appreciate you help please. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/229904/sharepoint-designer-create-workflow-to-schedule-emails-on-specific-dates-from

Comment: You already have received 2 answers.... do you need anything else?

Comment: Thank you for the comments on workflow. I am a novice to SharePoint, I will explore your answers further. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In your calculated column you have an image. You can not filter by image.

You could use another calculated columnd and put inside the value that you expect to be filtered.

Comment: My calculated column, 'Aging', is not an image. Data type = Number. What you are seeing in the filter display is the Formula in the Calculated column, which is the problem here. I want to display the value not the formula.

Answer (score 0):

What is your "Data Type" for the Calculated column? Please select **Number** as your type in calculated column for showing images in Calculated columns.

Comment: data type is NUMBER