# SharePoint designer - create workflow to schedule emails on specific dates from Calendar?

Tags: designer-workflow, sharepoint-calendar

I want to use a specific recurring calendar date to send out email to a list of recipients. In my calendar I have created a recurring event for the last Friday of every month. Event start time is 8 am. The idea is to trigger the email at 8 am on the specified day. 
My work flow condition is this - If the calendar date is the start time of my event, then send email. That is - `IF field equals value
  email some`

What is field and value for my case? Is this correct? Please help.

Calendar event
[image]
Workflow
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thank the gentlemen who helped give me support. I have a solution, but the workflow is not for a calendar (as stated in the question) but a list. My solution is as follows. I created a Sharepoint Custom list of Reminder dates for all months of the year. I have two columns - Title(default) and reminder date (data type = date only). **Before I added dates** as new items, I created the workflow in sharepoint designer for this list. I indicated in the workflow start options to 'Start workflow automatically when an item is created'. I saved then published.
Here is the workflow - `Pause until CurrentItem: mydates ; If currentItem: mydates equals Today; email my_recipients`

Now back in my list, go to standard view, add new items, i.e. the reminder dates for all the months. You will find a new column that shows 'In Progress'. This will change to 'Completed' once the email is sent. And I have received email on the scheduled date. It works.

Answer (score 2):

Well,
Workflows are triggered when an item is created or updated. If your intent is to send an email on a specific date, this will not work.

If you have access to the server:
I would create a Windows Task (Task Scheduler) and create a new Task, defining when it has to be run, running a powershell script. In such a script you could write anything.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/aa384006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[HowTo](https://www.howtogeek.com/123393/how-to-automatically-run-programs-and-set-reminders-with-the-windows-task-scheduler/)

[Example](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/7-nerdy-things-can-automate-windows-task-scheduler/)

You could create your calendar and use it as you described. Instead of writing a workflow write a PowerShell script, querying the SharePoint (in your case the calendar list), checking if there are entries on a specific day and send your email.

Example to send mails from powershell:

```
Send-MailMessage -From "emailFrom" -To "emailTo" -SmtpServer smtpServer -Subject "Subject" -Body "body"
```

Comment: Hi Emaborsa, from the articles you mentioned, I tried to use Windows Task scheduler, together with SENDEMAIL utility. I used the schedule options available in the Task scheduler instead of SP calendar. It failed, possibly because I didn't provide the port number, which I don't know, and can't ask for from the administrator. This powershell you mention, is it typed in cmd line? where does it reference the task or sendmail utility? can you break it down a bit please.

Comment: it's not types in the standard windows prompt line, but an improved one https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/fundamental/using-windows-powershell?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Hi Emaborsa, thank you for the powershell link. A person I talked to mentioned, he  has a working workflow, where he is subtracting 90 days from ExpiryDate, and if it is equal to today, sends email. Along the same line I thought, I will create a list of reminderDates for each month, say from dec17 to dec18. The workflow will check if the today = reminderDate, if it is then send email. But this isn't working. Any thoughts on this.

Comment: Hard to know/say. Update your question and post information.

Answer (score 1):

Emaborsa is right

> Well, Workflows are triggered when an item is created or updated.

For make this done. You could use the "Pause Until Date" action in the sharepoint workflow( and use the date from the column in the list) for saying the workflow that needs to be paused until the date comes.

[image: Pause until Date Action]

Comment: Hi JL, so you are suggestion that I create a list, with atleast 2 columns - 1) The email send date 2) Today's date (a calculated column) . So when the condition Today's date = Email send date, then trigger the email. Is this your suggestion? Thank you.