# Hyperlink in SharePoint Document Library

Tags: document-library, hyperlink

I have a document library that has additional columns filled with various types of data. One of these columns is set using a workflow in SPD as a hyperlink. For over a year this column did in fact appear as a hyperlink, as it should have. However, last week the hyperlink stopped appearing and in its place appeared HTML. Does anyone else have this same issue? Do you know of a way to fix it?

[image: workflow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are on the SharePoint online and calculated field was used to create the hyperlink which is not supported anymore by Microsoft. Have a look at [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f).

A possible workaround would be to:

1. Create a workflow
2. Build a string with appropriate URL/String
3. Update the item in the list (this means you will have to create another field and hide/remove the calculated field you currently have)

**Updated**

Workaround:

1. Create a new column, 'Hyperlink or Picture' type, ensure that it is
   Hyperlink
2. Create a workflow variable (which you already have Link), just remove all the HTML it should be something like:  https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Shared%20Documents/Forms/EditFile.aspx?ID=[%Current Item:ID%]&Source=Pending%20Approval.aspx
3. Immediately after the url **put a , (comma) and a space** followed the text you want to display.  This should be like: https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Shared%20Documents/Forms/EditFile.aspx?ID=[%Current Item:ID%]&Source=Pending%20Approval.aspx, Click Here to Approve
4. Set the variable to the Hyperlink field created.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response! Much appreciated.  To clarify my post from above, this IS a workflow, designed in SPD, not a calculated field, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Okay please update the question with the screenshot of the workflow so we can understand more.

Comment: this is updated with more information about the workflow.

Comment: It looks like MSFT stopped supporting this feature, even if it comes from a workflow :( https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I have updated my answer and it works for me.  Have a look at the answer from work around. I will add some screenshots tomorrow

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: yes! this seemed to work. Very creative :) Thank you!