# Correctly url path?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I upload photos into my sharepoint online into assets folder, when I go to that folder navigator bar shows:

```
https://mybusiness.sharepoint.com/siteassets/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2FSiteAssets%myFolder%2FIcons
```

So I want to use it into img src like:

```
<img src='~SiteAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2FSiteAssets%myFolder%2FIcons/IMAGE_1'>
```

But it don´t show photo... what is wrong with my src?

Comment: Why you have /Image_1'> after Icons' it should be />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the correct image URL, try to Get the image URL as shown below

[image]

And the relative path should look like

```
~sitecollection/SiteAssets/Qassas.png
```

The image tag should look like (based on the Site Asset location)

```
<img src='../../SiteAssets/Qassas.png'/>
```

Or

```
<img src="/SiteAssets/Qassas.png">
```

---

**[Update]**

Based on my conversation with OP in chat, he tried to use HTML tag in a calculated column in SharePoint online. **Unfortunately, it's blocked in 13/06/2017.**

> Some users have added HTML markup or script elements to calculated
>   fields. This is an undocumented use of the feature, and we will begin
>   blocking execution of custom markup in calculated fields in SharePoint
>   Online from June 13, 2017 onwards. We are also providing this as a
>   configurable option for on-premises in SharePoint Server 2016 and
>   SharePoint Server 2013 via the June 2017 and subsequent Public
>   Updates.

you can check the details at [Handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032106/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields)

Another thread discuss this topic with some alternatives at [June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64446/discussion-on-answer-by-m-qassas-correctly-url-path).