# Making a yes/no column show an icon rather than text

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, json-formatting, image

I'd like to have a Yes/No column that rather than showing the usual text ("Yes"/"No"), shows an icon - say green or red.

I know I can create another column (a calculated one) with a formula that depends on the value the value of the first column, something along these lines

```
="<center>" & IF([Status]="Yes";"<img src='/_layouts/images/yes.gif' border='0'/>";
ELSEIF([Status]="No";"<img src='/_layouts/images/no.GIF' border='0'/>";
```

But this solution effectively requires two columns: one for the users to update (the yes/no column), and another that shows the related icon. Is there a way to directly show the icons in the yes/no column?

Comment: You have tagged your question with both SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint Online. What plattform/version are you on?

Comment: HTML tag is blocked in calculated field SharePoint Online https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f

Comment: I am using Sharepoint online, not the desktop version. It is however a rather old version (not Office 365, but SP 2010 I guess, this is why I also initially tagged the question as 2010)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSLink feature. Edit your list view webpart, add JS link to the webpart to display icon instead of text.

Steps to implement JSLink - refer this blog http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2015/12/sharepoint-js-link-context-object.html

Similar requirement can be refered from here - [JSlink on color coded items](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/04/color-code-list-items-with-javascript-using-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SharePoint Online you should use JSON formatting, see these examples:
[example 1](http://www.constellationsolutions.com/how-to/check-mark-sharepoint-modern-list-column-format/)
[example 2](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/blob/master/column-samples/yesno-checkmark-format/yesno-checkmark-format.json)