# Help with Traffic Light SharePoint Calculated Formula

Tags: calculated-column-formula, json-formatting, formula, calculated-column, column-formatting

I am wanting to create a column called "Traffic Light" on an existing SharePoint Library.

Column Name = Traffic Light

Data Type = Single line of text

**Formula:**

```
="<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:"&IF([Review Status]="Approaching","Green",IF([Review Status]="OverDue,"Red","Yellow"))&";'>•</DIV>"
```

Despite my best endeavors I can't seem to get the correct syntax for this formula.

Help needed please.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below formula:

```
="<DIV style='font-weight:bold; font-size:24px; color:"&IF([Review Status]="Approaching","Green",IF([Review Status]="OverDue","Red","Yellow"))&";'>•</DIV>"
```

**Note**:

1. Return this field as **Number** field.
2. Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields for recent versions, see [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f).
3. If you are using SharePoint Online/2019 then you can use **[Column Formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#apply-conditional-formatting)** to achieve similar requirements.

**Update**:

You can add below JSON on the **Review Status** column(In `Column settings-->Format this column`) itself to show the colored column:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "padding": "0 4px"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": {
      "operator": ":",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "==",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "toLowerCase",
              "operands": [
                "@currentField"
              ]
            },
            {
              "operator": "toLowerCase",
              "operands": [
                "Approaching"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "sp-css-backgroundColor-successBackground50",
        {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "toLowerCase",
                  "operands": [
                    "@currentField"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "operator": "toLowerCase",
                  "operands": [
                    "OverDue"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "sp-css-backgroundColor-errorBackground50",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "toLowerCase",
                      "operands": [
                        "@currentField"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "operator": "toLowerCase",
                      "operands": [
                        "In Progress"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "sp-css-backgroundColor-warningBackground50",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "==",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "toLowerCase",
                          "operands": [
                            "@currentField"
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "operator": "toLowerCase",
                          "operands": [
                            ""
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "sp-css-backgroundColor-blueBackground07",
                    ""
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

[image]

**Creating another column and Referencing Review Status**:

Use below code:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "=if([$Review_x0020_Status] == '', '', '•')",
    "style": {
        "color": "=if([$Review_x0020_Status] == 'Not Due', 'green', if([$Review_x0020_Status] == 'OverDue', 'red', if([$Review_x0020_Status] == 'Approaching','yellow','white')))",
        "font-size": "5em"
    }
}
```

**Note**: Use internal name of `Review Status` column, you can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96827/discussion-on-answer-by-ganesh-sanap-help-with-traffic-light-sharepoint-calculat).