# Color based on value in SharePont Online task list (added app)

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, column-formatting

Using SharePoint through my company's 365 account, had a need for a clean list with parent/child relationship, the subtasks in the Task List app fit the bill nicely, out of the box, but now I feel my hands are tied. I tried to apply JSON formatting to a column like I did in another list and it just won't work. Trying to display a colored background to a row/column/dot, to indicate status.  I had to add it via list settings, no column formatting when I click on the heading of the column.  Is this possible?

Comment: Check my answer at [Help with Traffic Light SharePoint Calculated Formula](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/267093/help-with-traffic-light-sharepoint-calculated-formula/267094#267094)

Comment: It doesn't seem to apply with the 'task' app's list. I can get this to work 8 different ways in a traditional list so far, but the JSON doesn't do anything in the added "tasks" built in app.

Comment: Are you using classic experience or modern experience?

Comment: That appears to have fixed that, but then broke the task name and started displaying a number... ready to give up.

Comment: Appreciate your help, Ganesh, the new experience view will show the colors properly, but task names show as numbers, so it's not going to work until MS fixes things.

Comment: Can you please add any screenshot or your code? What exactly the issue you are facing today? That will be helpful to solve your issue.