# Show color based on %Complete number column value

Tags: 2016, custom-list

Hi I have a task list in SharePoint 2016 Team Site and based on %Complete number column value is any way to show a progress bar type color indicator  column, if task 0-50 % it show red color and 50-100 % it show green color.

Comment: You can use JSLink and CSR for such requirements in classic experience. Check [this reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251405/how-to-highlight-a-row-on-active-status/251416#251416). It might be possible using HTML in calculated column in SP on-premises. But, better use JSLink which gives you more flexibility and control using custom code.

Comment: Please can you share any example for custom list and can i do without SP Designer?

Comment: Yes, you can do it without designer. You can use JS code and content editor/script editor web part. Here's example using calculated column: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/267093/help-with-traffic-light-sharepoint-calculated-formula/267094#267094

Comment: Please share for SharePoint 2016 and for Task List, above example will work for SP 2016?

Comment: CSR (JSLink) and calculated columns work in SP 2016. Read my above comments carefully.

Comment: Please can you share an example i tried may ways but it not worked for my tasklist and column %complete